# Using PendingIntent in unit test to test a service

Tags: android, unit-testing, service, android-pendingintent, servicetestcase

I've got a `IntentService` (actually a [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)!) that returns result to requests (i.e., from activities) using a `PendingIntent` that is added to the intent used to start the service. Earlier I used `ResultReceiver` but found that it crashes if the device goes to sleep or is rotated while the request is being handled.

As unit test for this service I'm using the `ServiceTestCase<Service>` class. That worked fine when using `ResultReceiver` since it could be added to the intent passed to the service. However, `ServiceTestCase` does not contain Activity's `createPendingResult` method.

Therefore I wonder what's the best approach for testing this service. Should I use ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 or `ActivityUnitTestCase` instead for my unit test? Or any better ideas?

Btw, I read in the Android Dev. guide chapter on Services the following:

> "However, if you want the service to send a result back, then the client that starts the service can create a PendingIntent for a broadcast (with getBroadcast()) and deliver it to the service in the Intent that starts the service. The service can then use the broadcast to deliver a result."

Using broadcasts for a `IntentService` that is local to the activities sounds like overkill to me, but I'll be happy to hear others' opinions on that.